# Что быстрее innerHTML или createElement appendChild

Tags: javascript, dom

### предисловие

```
document.body.innerHTML = `тут очень большое дерево`
```

если создавать очень большое дерево, то ИМХО присвоение(`=`) в `innerHTML` быстрее чем создание дерева с помощью JS. а вот как быть с наращиванием (`+=`) ?

1. один вариант

   ```
   document.body.innerHTML += `<span>что-то простое, одноуровневое</span>`
   ```
2. другой

   ```
   document.body.innerHTML += `ещё одно очень большое дерево`
   ```

---

этот небольшой тест показал, что "наращивание" создаёт все элементы заново

```js
// html - переводит Raw строку в строку.
// а так же даёт подсветку html в VSCode с помощью плагина
// lit-html https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bierner.lit-html
let html = (tsa, ...args) => String.raw(tsa, ...args);
// --
const { counterConteiner, counter } = Counter();
document.body.innerHTML = '';
document.body.appendChild(counterConteiner);
// --
void function () {
    let i = 0;
    class TestEl extends HTMLElement {
        constructor() {
            //@ts-ignore
            super(...arguments);
            this.id = '' + i++;
            counter[this.id] = 0;
        }
        connectedCallback() {
            counter[this.id]++;
            this.innerHTML = `counter[${this.id}] ${counter[this.id]}`;
        }
    }
    customElements.define('test-el', TestEl);
}();
// -----------------
// --
let conteiner = document.createElement('div');
document.body.appendChild(conteiner);
conteiner.innerHTML += html `<test-el> </test-el><br>`;
conteiner.innerHTML += html `<span>-,-</span><br>`;
conteiner.innerHTML += html `<span>-,-</span><br>`;
// --
let test = conteiner.getElementsByTagName('test-el')[0];
test.remove();
conteiner.appendChild(test);
// --
// -----------------
function Counter() {
    let counter = new Proxy({}, {
        set(target, key, value, receiver) {
            try {
                if (key in target)
                    counterRender(key, value);
                else {
                    counterRender();
                    counterRender(key, value);
                }
                target[key] = value;
            }
            catch (_e) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
    let counterConteiner = document.createElement('table');
    let counterRender = (key, value) => {
        if (value == 0)
            return;
        if (key)
            counterConteiner.innerHTML += html `
            <tr>
                <td>test-el id="${key}"</td>
                <td>counts ${value}</td>
            </tr>`;
        else
            counterConteiner.innerHTML += html `
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>`;
    };
    return { counterConteiner, counter };
}
//# sourceMappingURL=index.js.map
```

что странно, если учесть существование таких элементов как `HTMLTemplateElement` и `DocumentFragment`. (наверное, просто так положено по стандарту, и по тому же стандарту, для наращивания нужно использовать `insertAdjacentHTML` [доки](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML))

### вопрос

не смотря на приведённый тест, вопрос ещё актуален.
что быстрее: присвоение `innerHTML` или создание через `JS` ?

и тот же вопрос, желательно с примерами, но в контексте `ShadowRoot` ?

Comment: в чем заключается вопрос? ты спросил что быстрее? сделал тест, быстрее оказался один из вариантов. В чем суть оставшегося вопроса?

Comment: @Grundy, вы не правы. 1)мой тест лишь показывает, что элементы создаются заново, что не означает что это дольше 2) я в самом конце есть второй вопрос - как это происходит в `ShadowRoot` 3) считаете разработчиков хрома глупыми?

Comment: Как вообще вопрос к разработчикам хрома относится?

Comment: если бы вы сказали, что так происходит потому, что положено по стандарту, и по тому же стандарту есть `insertAdjacentHTML` я бы с удовольствием признал вашу правоту, НО это также не отменят моего вопроса (что быстрее) и уж тем более вопроса как оно в ШР. вы снова(вопрос про массивы) выдираете из контекста кусок, ещё и наименее значимый. да, наверное вы правы, по третьему пункту, спасибо за помощь. я очень вам признателен.

Comment: [If you have two horses and you want to know which of the two is the faster then race your horses.](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/) Стоит добавить в каких именно браузерах актуален вопрос.

Comment: Быстрее засучить рукава и делать так, как удобнее. Вообще насколько я понял `*.innerHTML += newline` == `*.innerHTML = *.innerHTML + newline`, так что разницы нет абсолютно.